# SQL query (self-join needed?)

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table with multiple fields and two i.d fields, one field is called regular_id and second is called special.

Each row can have a value under regular_id and special_id, if there is a value under special_id then it exists somewhere else in the table as a regular_id.

I want to build a query that says -

Give me all rows where the special_id field is null, but the value in the regular_id field does not exist anywhere else ( in any other row/record) in that table under the special field.

Comment: share sample data and output

Comment: Seems simple, what do you have so far?

Comment: So far im thinking to try a self join? but not sure - 

 im not sure how to share sample data or output here?

Sample data would just be a row with multiple fields and the two fields concerned are the two i.d fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: Untested.

```
select A.*
from table A
where A.special_id is null
and not exists (select 1 from table B where B.special_id = A.regular_id)
```

Of-course A and B are aliases for the same database table.

Comment: I think you have special id and regular id roles swapped here.

Comment: Paraphrasing part of the original question... *regular_id field does not exist in the special field*

Comment: sorry swapped in the B.special_id = A.regular_id ? should it be the other way around or this is what it should be based on question?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer - UNTESTED, because you didn't provide sample data and I also don't have the EMP table that @John Martin referred to in his answer.

Comment: The query is correct. (Or the description in the request is wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

Sub-query or exist can do.

This is very similar to the famous scott.EMP table in Oracle.

```
create table emp(  
  empno    number(4,0),  
  ename    varchar2(10),  
  job      varchar2(9),  
  mgr      number(4,0),  
  hiredate date,  
  sal      number(7,2),  
  comm     number(7,2),  
  deptno   number(2,0),  
  constraint pk_emp primary key (empno),  
  constraint fk_deptno foreign key (deptno) references dept (deptno)  
)
```

So regular_id in your question is the empno (employee ID) in scott.EMP table and special_id is the mgr (manager ID)

Now your question translates to scott.EMP:
where mgr field is null, but the value in the empno field does not exist anywhere else (in any other row/record) in that table under the mgr field.

```
select m.*
from scott.EMP m
where m.mgr IS NULL
and m.empno not in (select mgr from scott.EMP where mgr is not null)
```

*thanks for Thorsten Kettner's correction, always pay attention to NULL in list*

Your question translates to natural language:
    `The person who has no manager and is not manager of any employee.`

Comment: This is an incorrect solution. See my example and look at the sample data/result.

Comment: `NOT IN` behaves strange with nulls. Once there is a null in the list, the expression is not true. So either use `NOT EXISTS` and make the subquery correlated or stay with `NOT IN` but exclude nulls in your subquery: `where mgr is not null`.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten Kettner, I forgot the NULL in the list

Answer (score 1):

**A self join is the right way to go.**

```
SELECT a.special_id, a.regular_id
FROM tablename  a
LEFT JOIN tablename b
    ON a.regular_id = b.special_id 
WHERE a.special_id IS NULL
AND b.special_id IS NULL;
```

Note: Replace tablename with your actual table name.

**Sample Data:**

```
REGULAR_ID  SPECIAL_ID
1           1
1           2
2           1
3           1
1           NULL
3           NULL
```

**Result:**

```
REGULAR_ID  SPECIAL_ID
3           NULL
```

Comment: I very much prefer `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` over your solution, because they select rows from the table `where not exists` certain other rows. So they select from the one table you want to have data for and put criteria (the lookup) in the `WHERE` clause where it belongs in my opinion. Your solution, though, is not uncommon. It's called an **anti join** and is often used on young DBMS that still have performance issues with `IN` and `EXISTS` clauses. A trick I would only use when forced to. Anyway, that is my point of view, and others may see this differently.

Comment: Anyway, your answer shows Chris90 how to show sample data and expected result. This should help him with his next requests. My upvote for this. (And the query is correct, too, of course.)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @ThorstenKettner